# Login screen suddenly stays black

Tags: ubuntu, login, intel-graphics

I set up a Tuxedo InfinityBook Pro 14 Gen7 (without NVIDIA) and so far everything worked very well. The OS is based on Ubuntu 22.04 (TuxedoOS), the latest version of KDE Plasma.

After switching on today, the device boots but the login screen remains black. If I put the system into standby and press a key, the login screen flashes briefly and then goes black again.

The key combination CTRL + ALT + F1/F2/F3 does not help either - the screen is black.

Booting into recovery mode works. Does anyone have a tip on how to fix this?

**dmesg output**
https://pastebin.com/uzV6ZCSE

Answer (score 1):

After uninstalling SDDM and re-installing it, the Login Screen is back.